# Last 3 digits of $2012^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the base $10$ expansion of $2012^n$ is $?\,?\,?\ldots ?\,4\,?\,4$ where $?$ is an unknown digit.

Find all the possible values of the digit between the $4$s.

Comment: The $2000$ is superfluous, so consider $12^n$

Comment: You mean $x_1\,x_2\,x_3\ldots x_s\,4\,x_{s+2}\,4$ where $x_i,\, i=1,\dots,s,s+2$ are unknowns.

Comment: A quick Python program yields $2012^{30} \bmod 1000 = 424$ and $2012^{74} \bmod 1000 = 464$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: to get the ones digit to be $4$, the power must be $2+4k$. The last three digits recur at least by $\phi(1000)=400$, so it is easy to use a spreadsheet to compute them using $=mod (up*12^4,1000)$ and look.